# Does "server side rendering" mean two sides rendering?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Need some clear understanding... When we do server side rendering the app actually renders twice.

1) with `renderToString` function on server.

2) with `render` function on client (when page came from server).

And the whole point of React server side rendering is to use SEO.

Am I right or do I miss something ? Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Server side rendering is a technique to deliver the rendered data to the client, while retaining the ability to use variable bindings. This can be faster or slower, depending on the amount of the data.

There's almost zero duplicated code executed. The code delivered to client side will migrate the rendered state calculated by the server to the structure that the browser can process (which is identical to a loaded client-side rendered page).